# How to Shutdown WSL from inside the Linux distro (e.g Ubuntu) environment

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

So, I totally begineer at WSL and I have installed and running WSL. And, I found that I can enter the default distro by just typing `wsl` and pressing.
But, how to exit from the same terminal, without going into powershell window and then typing `wsl --shutdown`

Want to Shutdown WSL distro from within the same terminal and flexiblity to shift from Wsl to powershell mode within the same terminal on desire. In simple terms to exit the linux distro and get back to powershell mode just like I can get into distro mode by using wsl command.

Comment: Keep in mind that questions on Stack Overflow should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. "unique to software development")*. For information on how to determine if a WSL question is programming-related (and where to post if it isn't), please see the [WSL tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/info).  Also worth reading some of the answers (mine included) under the Ask Ubuntu question, [Can't restart/shutdown Ubuntu under WSL](https://askubuntu.com/q/1131122/1165986).  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking for, possibly the `exit` command, to go to the parent session ? -- You can open windows powershell (powershell.exe) and ex: ubuntu WSL in [tabs using **WindowsTerminal**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) -- and [You can install Powershell on linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.3) -- then run it like normal `pwsh` -- note `windows powershell` ( `powershell.exe`) is the deprecated version, you want powershell `pwsh.exe` for both windows and linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To shutdown WSL from inside a Linux distro :

```
wsl.exe -t $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
```